# Select a non null column, when there are multiple columns with the same name

Tags: mysql

I have two tables abc, def

```
abc has the following columns  "value","timeStamp"
def has the columns "value","timeStamp"<
```

Now i would like to select

```
select abc.value as `ABC Value`,def.value as `DEF Value`,if( abc.timeStamp is not null) abc.timeStamp or else def.timeStamp if def.timeStamp is not null' from abc,def;
```

How could i achieve this

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't think you can use if in a Select like that, I am pretty sure that you would need to use a case statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html
`if` can only be used in Stored Procedures / Functions in MySQL

You are looking for `case` syntax.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using CASE expression like this:

```
select abc.value as `ABC Value`,
       def.value as `DEF Value`,
       case when abc.timeStamp is not null then abc.timeStamp else def.timeStamp as `timeStamp`
from abc,def;
```

I'm assuming that you want to join this table by the common column value(and make a full outer join that doesn't exists in mysql, so you need two left joins) , so you should have a join condition( I will also change your implicit join syntax to the proper syntax of join)

```
select abc.value as `ABC Value`,
       def.value as `DEF Value`,
       case when def.timeStamp is not null then def.timeStamp else abc.timeStamp as `timeStamp`
from abc  
LEFT OUTER JOIN def ON(abc.value = def.value)
UNION
select abc.value as `ABC Value`,
       def.value as `DEF Value`,
       case when abc.timeStamp is not null then abc.timeStamp else def.timeStamp as `timeStamp`
from def 
LEFT OUTER JOIN abc ON(abc.value = def.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce() function to achive the desired results. Pls note, that if both timestamp columns are null, then it will return null:

```
select abc.value as `ABC Value`,def.value as `DEF Value`,
       coalesce( abc.timeStamp, def.timeStamp) as ts
from abc,def;
```

Comment: What "desired result"?

Comment: Select a single non-null column out of multiple columns in a specific order.